# Python turtle arrowheads not facing in correct direction

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw an arrow using Python turtle. But when it gets to the head of the arrow, I get the turtle heading and add 45 degrees to draw half of the arrow, then get back to the same position to draw the other part.  I set the correct angle but then everything goes wrong:

## Initialization

```
StartPointX=0
StartPointY=0
MaxX=100
MaxY=100
```

## Drawing The arrow line

```
Brush.goto(StartPointX,StartPointY)
Brush.goto(MaxX,MaxY)
```

## Drawing arrow head

```
Brush.left(45)
Brush.backward(20)
Brush.forward(20)
Brush.right(90)
Brush.backward(20)
```

Output image:

[image: Output Image Here]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [mcve] showing your full code that makes it easy to reproduce the problem. It's unclear what `StartPointX`, `MaxX` etc are.

Comment: @ggorlen is that okay? :D

Comment: What does "everything goes wrong" mean? _How exactly_ is it going wrong?

Comment: @ForceBru I added an image of the output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're ignoring the *heading* of the turtle.  When you use `goto()` the heading of the turtle is unchanged. When you write `left(45)`, it's left 45 degrees relative to what?  Left of the current heading, which hasn't been set:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

StartPointX = 0
StartPointY = 0
MaxX = 100
MaxY = 100

screen = Screen()
brush = Turtle()

# Drawing The arrow line

brush.penup()
brush.goto(StartPointX, StartPointY)
brush.pendown()

brush.setheading(brush.towards(MaxX, MaxY))
brush.goto(MaxX, MaxY)

# Drawing arrow head

brush.left(45)
brush.backward(20)
brush.forward(20)
brush.right(90)
brush.backward(20)

brush.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Another way to approach this:

```
MaxX = 100
MaxY = 100

# ...

brush.setheading(brush.towards(MaxX, MaxY))
brush.goto(MaxX, MaxY)
```

Is to control the heading and use `forward()` instead of `goto()`:

```
Distance = 140

# ...

brush.setheading(45)
brush.forward(Distance)
```